# Why does casting object's address to same class as this points to results in another object value?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, casting, watch

I have an object of the class RTSG::XML3D::OpenGLMeshMA. When stopped at the breakpoint in its method RTSG::XML3D::OpenGLMeshMA::onXflowStateChanged I add the following expressions into the Watch window:

[image]

How can it be that the raw address of the object casted into the same pointer type as this results in a different object (object and uniqieId members have different values in the first and second rows)?

System info: VS 2008 3.5 SP1, Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: I would guess, although I cannot find documentation for it, that _this_ is the internal reference to the object. While your first is the external reference to it.  Which explains why you can only use _this_ within an instance, it has no external reference.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake What is _internal reference_ and how is it different from _external reference_? These are pointers, not references, aren't they?

Comment: A pointer is a reference in the general sense. See [this (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for the C# version.

Comment: I see your point now. I got confused because C++ also has references (Foo&). I wonder why would an object have different pointer externally and internally? Could `vtable` be related here? Note also that external pointer refers to uninitialized heap memory pattern (0xCDCDCDCD). Maybe this hints on something.

Comment: I wonder why the question talks about .NET versions and 64bit, and we are looking at C++ and 32bit pointers at the same time.

Comment: RTSG::XML3D::OpenGLMeshMA does indeed have a multiple inheritance. However, it has only one real base class and the rest are mostly pure virtual interfaces. One of the interfaces forms a diamond pattern and has virtual non-pure destructor - could it be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable explanation (other than a debugger bug) is that you're using multiple inheritance. The start of the object is not `0x0a72d4e4`, it's somewhere else (probably a pointer higher or lower). The line with the cast is forcing the debugger to treat that address as the start of the object, and accordingly it's reading bad values.

With multiple inheritance, the value of 'this' can be different from the address of the start of the object, and the compiler inserts adjustments as necessary. It's discussed in e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056790/c-multiple-inheritance-memory-addressing-issue), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx).

Comment: -1: Both expressions shown have the same type.  Multiple inheritance cannot explain that.  There is no such thing as "start of the object" independent of its type, as any object can be a subobject (in layout terms) of a derived object (in inheritance terms).

Comment: Of course the top object shows the same type as the object in the second line. It's been C-style cast.

Comment: Of course it does.  And multiple inheritance can only explain a different interpretation of the same pointer when the *type* is different.  Suppose that "this" is actually a pointer to OpenGLMeshMA subobject of a derived object that inherits, non-virtually, from multiple OpenGLMeshMA's, absurd as it seems.  Even then, there is no way how the two (same) pointers would be pointing to different instances of OpenGLMeshMA within the object.  There must be something else happening to this IDE.

Comment: I have no idea what happened back then, but must be some kind of debugger bug.